# RTRT module type errir

Tags: arm, endianness, greenhills, rtrt

I have an issue when i running my IBM Rational Test RealTime tool.
its tells me that my **module differs in machine type or endianness**

i've checked all the configuration and everything is in **little endian**

I've checked my compiler and my linker they have access to GHS repository for an ARM target

Where do I update the configuration?